# Is this kingdom from the Sleeping Beauty alternate opening meant to be Ulstead?

Tags: disney, maleficent, maleficent-mistress-of-evil, sleeping-beauty

In an alternate opening to Sleeping Beauty, we are shown King Hubert’s kingdom, which is home to him and his son, Prince Phillip.

In Maleficent Mistress of Evil, Prince Phillip’s kingdom is called Ulstead.

So could King Hubert’s kingdom be an early version of Ulstead? Assuming it was given that name in Sleeping Beauty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No, King Hubert’s kingdom is never named. Ulstead was invented several years later, and the Prince Phillip of Ulstead’s father is John.

King Hubert and Prince Phillip’s kingdom in Disney’s Sleeping Beauty released in 1959 would not have been an early version of Ulstead, because it was never named, and Ulstead was created for a much later movie released in 2019. Furthermore, the kingdoms are ruled over by different kings. The king of the kingdom in Disney’s Sleeping Beauty is King Hubert. Also, the queen of this kingdom is never mentioned nor is she seen during any of the events that King Hubert and Prince Phillip attend - there may not be a living queen.

> Narrator:
> Thus on this great and joyous day did all the kingdom celebrate the long awaited royal birth. And good King Stefan and his Queen made welcome their lifelong friend.
>
> Announcer: Their royal highnesses, King Hubert and Prince Phillip.
>
> Narrator: Fondly had these monarchs dreamed one day their kingdoms to unite. Thus today would they announce that Phillip, Hubert’s son and heir to Stefan's child would be betrothed. And so to her his gift he brought, and looked, unknowing, on his future bride. 
> <sub><sup>*- Sleeping Beauty (1959)*</sup></sub>

The king of Ulstead is called John, and the queen of Ulstead is called Ingrith.

> Prince Phillip: This is my father, King John of Ulstead. And my mother, Queen Ingrith. 
> <sub><sup>*- Maleficent: Mistress of Evil (2019)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, the relationships between King Hubert’s kingdom and King Stefan’s kingdom and Ulstead and the Moors are different as well. King Hubert and King Stefan were lifelong friends and wanted their children to marry because of their existing closeness - the marriage of Phillip and Aurora would simply unite their kingdoms even further. However, Ulstead and the Moors had a contentious relationship, and it was hoped that the marriage of Phillip and Aurora would bring peace to both kingdoms.

Therefore, while King Hubert’s kingdom from Sleeping Beauty and Ulstead are each known as the kingdom that Prince Phillip’s father rules over in their respective movies, they cannot be considered the same kingdom.

Answer (score 0):

Uh, No. The movie never said it. However the 2019 Maleficent: Mistress of Evil does give Hubert’s kingdom a name called Ulstead while Hubert is renamed King John.

Not counting the 2019 film, Hubert’s queen is never mentioned or shown at all in the original 1959 film.
as he and Phillip attend the christening birth of Baby Aurora, announced by King Stefan’s head messenger and majordomo, Lord Duke.

The relationship of the kingdoms between Hubert and Stefan are different in the Maleficent films unlike the original.